# Select adjacent data based on values in cells

Tags: excel, if-statement, integer, excel-formula, worksheet-function

I have a giant Excel file that contains a time column and a data column. In two new columns I'd like to pull the time and the corresponding data (same row) when a new second begins based on the time column's value. The number of rows per second is not consistent, so I can't use a linear offset. The time (A) and data (B) columns are formatted as follows:

```
Time        Data  
163010.3838 0.009332522  
163010.8468 0.009332853  
163011.3099 0.009332936  
163011.7749 0.00933318  
163012.2399 0.009334042  
163012.7049 0.00933733  
163013.168  0.009335146  
163013.633  0.009332692  
163014.098  0.009335718  
163014.5631 0.009334616  
163015.0271 0.009334818  
163015.4921 0.009336317   
163015.9571 0.009335719
```

Time is in the format hhmmss.decimal value as seen. In adjacent columns (say C and D) I want to pull the time and data values of each row whenever a new second is reached. So it would look like:

```
Time   Data  
163010 0.009332522   
163011 0.009332936      
163012 0.009334042
```

and so forth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `Time` is in A1, please try in C2:

```
=INT(A2)
```

In D2:

```
=B2
```

and in D3:

```
=IF(INT(A3)>INT(A2),B3,"")
```

both first and last above copied down to suit.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't think I showed the full extent of the problem initially. Please see updated data set

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a data setup and desired results that looks like this:

[image: tigeravatar example for Hyung]

In cell D2 and copied down is this formula:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(INT($A$2:$A$14),MATCH(0,INDEX(COUNTIF(D$1:D1,INT($A$2:$A$14)),),0)),"")
```

In cell E2 and copied down is this formula:

```
=IF(D2="","",INDEX($B$2:$B$14,MATCH(D2,INDEX(INT($A$2:$A$14),),0)))
```

Comment: This works for a small dataset but for one that is thousands of rows the processing time required to execute that formula so many times doesn't seem workable. :/

Comment: Could use a solution similar to pnuts' suggestion.  Alternately if you're not averse to VBA, a workable and efficient solution could be developed by recording a macro and doing those steps, then cleaning up the recorded code.

Comment: Will use pnuts' as I won't have to repeat this too many times. Thanks for the help!